# Remove prices in featured products in a Magento app.

Tags: php, magento

My Magento site does not need a shopping cart.

I was able to remove the prices and the shopping cart, but not the prices displayed on the featured products.

How can I remove them?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: Edit your featured product .phtml file

```
//change from
$category_id = "25"; // category_id for "Featured Products"
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
  ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'), 'inner')
  ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id));

//to

$category_id = "25"; // category_id for "Featured Products"
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
  ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'small_image'), 'inner')
  ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tx a lot fr ur help.. Couldnt use ur solution as my theme is kinda different. I figured it tho :)